# Does Google Adsense not acknowledge their code if it is put in with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, adsense

I have a Google Adsense ad that will show or not show depending on whether or not the user is logged in, and the code that writes it out is in Javascript. I have (I believe) enabled crawler access in the Adsense interface in accordance with their instructions.

Unfortunately, it seems the ad is not displaying. Here is the code:

```
document.getElementById("google-ad").innerHTML = '<script type="text/javascript"><!--\n\
google_ad_client = "ca-pub-0000000000000000";\n\
/* MySite */\n\
google_ad_slot = "0000000000";\n\
google_ad_width = 320;\n\
google_ad_height = 50;\n\
//-->\n\
</script>\n\
<script type="text/javascript"\n\
src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js">\n\
</script>';
```

I have been up and down all of Google's help section and troubleshooting guides to make sure I am in compliance with all their technical and policy guidelines. Eventually, I contacted Google support, and I got a response saying:

> I reviewed your site, but I wasn't able to find our ad code in the
>   HTML source of your pages.

Knowing that the goal of customer support is to dismiss people as quickly as possible, I want to make sure that when I write back to them that I do so with a concrete and sensible response that clarifies the issue so that they can't just wave it away with a cut and paste dismissal.

It seems from their response Google Customer Support is looking at the HTML code *before* Javascript writes in the code. I know that if I look at the source of the page in Firefox then it will not be visible, but if I look at the page with Firebug then the Javascript generated content is apparent.

However, if I write them and say "the AdSense Ad is included using Javascript", then their answer will almost certainly be "check your Javascript"(as if I haven't a thousand times already) or merely "don't do that."

Before I fight that fight, is there any reason to believe that what I'm doing shouldn't work? Don't people include Google code with Javascript all the time?

Is there a way that I can include the ad using Javascript which will be more likely to satisfy their requirements?

---

**Additional note:** When I look at my code in Firebug, I see some additional code appended with the code from Google which makes it look to me that the Google Ad contacted the Google servers and got some kind of response back, even though the ads are not displaying. So I'm extra surprised when they say they "can't see the ad code." Here's what it looks like in Firebug:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100%, but I'm fairly sure you should be able to use JS to append in the google ad script. However, if this ad only displays when a user logs in, then presumably the Google Support Person won't have logged in and therefore the script won't be triggered. Furthermore, the Adsense crawler won't have access to your pages (and won't display ads). If you visit http://support.google.com/adsense/bin/answer.py?hl=en-GB&answer=10532 it provides details on how to explicitly allow crawler access.

This depends on the ads being displayed when logged in, not the other way around. Apologies if it's no help!

Comment: Sorry for not making it more clear in the question, but I have already allowed crawler access. I thought I implied that when I said "I have been up and down all of Google's help section and troubleshooting guides to make sure I am in compliance with all their technical and policy guidelines." But I guess I could be more explicit.

Comment: Hi Dave, my bad! Sorry I couldn't help more.